# Create Simple Class with multiple calculating function( )

Tags: swift, function, class, addition

Trying to run a simple calculation via a function in my class. I simply want to add bill1 + bill2 and  print the total amount spent on bills. So (bill1 + bill2 = total). And then print the total amount.

Current error states - "Code after 'return' will never be executed." Now, is my location for my print in the wrong location or did I declare my variables incorrectly? Should I be using vars instead of lets?

What do you recommend for my function in order to calculate and print the result?

---

```
class BillsCalculator
{
    let nameOfBill1: String = "Medical"
    let nameOfBill1: String = "Hulu"
    let monthlyBillAmount1: Double = 34.25
    let monthlyBillAmount2: Double = 7.99
    let calculateTotalsPerMonth: Double = 0.0

   //calculateTotalPerMonth ( = monthlyBillAmount_1 + monthlyBillAmount_2 + 3)

    func calculateTotalsPerMonth(monthlyBillAmount: Double, monthlyBillAmount2: Double) -> Double
    {
        //totalBillsPerMonth = add(monthlyBillAmount1 + monthlyBillAmount2)
        return totalBillsPerMonth(monthlyBillAmount1 + monthlyBillAmount2)
*Error        println("You spend \(totalBillsPerMonth)")

    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

***First***: *"Code after 'return' will never be executed."*

Yes it will not, after you call return you exit the function and return to the function that call it, you probably have an warning in XCode warning you about telling you that

***Second***: *"Should I be using vars instead of lets"*

If the value changes you **MUST** use var, if it does not you **SHOULD** use let.

Some problems I can see in your code:

```
class BillsCalculator
{
    //use _ in the beginning of the name for class variables
    //eg. _nameOfBill instead nameOfBill1
    //It is not wrong use nameOfBill1 is just not recommended 
    //if nameOfBill1 change use var
    let nameOfBill1: String = "Medical"
    //Why is this declare twice
    let nameOfBill1: String = "Hulu" 
    //Those values look like change should be var
    var monthlyBillAmount1: Double = 34.25
    var monthlyBillAmount2: Double = 7.99
    var calculateTotalsPerMonth: Double = 0.0
    func calculateTotalsPerMonth(monthlyBillAmount: Double, monthlyBillAmount2: Double) -> Double
    {
        totalBillsPerMonth = add(monthlyBillAmount1 + monthlyBillAmount2)
        //print before return
        println("You spend \(totalBillsPerMonth)")
        return totalBillsPerMonth(monthlyBillAmount1 + monthlyBillAmount2)

    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for looking into this. I have _bill1 & _bill2 in my comment but not sure why I didn't catch those matching variables. I may change the _bills to var as well, since it may change.

Comment: I am glad I could help, let us know if it is all working now and don't forget to mark one of the answers as correct if it do :) Good luck finishing your app!

Answer (score 0):

Here you should either print the value of your total bill or return that value. As you just want to print the total bill amount so I would recommend you to just print, not to return anything. You can refer the below code.

```
class BillsCalculator
{
    let nameOfBill1: String = "Medical"
    let nameOfBill1: String = "Hulu"
    let monthlyBillAmount1: Double = 34.25
    let monthlyBillAmount2: Double = 7.99
    let calculateTotalsPerMonth: Double = 0.0

   //calculateTotalPerMonth ( = monthlyBillAmount_1 + monthlyBillAmount_2 + 3)

    func calculateTotalsPerMonth(monthlyBillAmount: Double, monthlyBillAmount2: Double) -> Double
    {
        calculateTotalsPerMonth= add(monthlyBillAmount1 + monthlyBillAmount2)
             println("You spend : "+totalBillsPerMonth);

    }
}
```

Comment: You comments about the function didn't work. 

Errors: use of unresolved identifier 'add' & the other error: keeps changing no matter what I change in the println( ). 

Any suggestions as I like your format the best and it made the most sense, but something is missing.

Comment: Just replace  calculateTotalsPerMonth= add(monthlyBillAmount1 + monthlyBillAmount2); with calculateTotalsPerMonth= (monthlyBillAmount1 + monthlyBillAmount2);

Answer (score 0):

One tiny error in your code

```
    let nameOfBill1: String = "Medical"
    let nameOfBill1: String = "Hulu"
```

These two variables have the same name, perhaps one should be:

```
    let nameOfBill2: String = "Hulu"
```

And yes return is always the last line in the function, so any codes after return will never be executed. If you only want to get the total of two bills, you can simply do this:

```
    func calculateTotalsPerMonth(monthlyBillAmount: Double, monthlyBillAmount2: Double) -> Double {
         //println("You spend \(totalBillsPerMonth)")
         return monthlyBillAmount1 + monthlyBillAmount2
     }
```

and call this function with your bill variables, like:

```
    let bill1 = 34.25
    let bill2 = 7.99
    let totalBill = calculateTotalsPerMonth(bill1, bill2)
    println("You spent \(totalBill)")
```

Swift is a very smart language, and it is type safe. You can remove the type if you want, more like a personal programming style thing.

```
    let bill1: Double = 34.25
    let bill1 = 34.25
```

They both will be type "Double"

Answer (score 0):

As others have said, you need to put your `println` statement before `return` since returns ends the execution of the method; thus `println` will never be run.

However, I would suggest a few changes to your current approach:

```
// A bill is an object - why not encapsulate it in a struct.
struct Bill {
    let name: String
    let amount: Double
}

// Using structs is generally preferred, unless you need inheritance and/or
// references to your BillsCalculator objects.
struct BillsCalculator {
    let bill1: Bill
    let bill2: Bill

    // Using a read-only computed property means you don't need to set 
    // the total to have an initial value of zero.
    var totalBilled: Double {
        return bill1.amount + bill2.amount
    }
}

// Since you're probably going to want to reuse BillsCalculator, 
// don't have each bill set already. Instead, use BillsCalculator's 
// initialiser and pass in bills.
let bill1 = Bill(name: "Medical", amount: 34.25)
let bill2 = Bill(name: "Hulu",    amount: 7.99)
let cal = BillsCalculator(bill1: bill1, bill2: bill2)

print("You've spend \(cal.totalBilled) this month")
```

Comment: Your struct suggestion worked. I'm doing this in xcode playground, and your suggestions has given my recent project some confidence.

Structs weren't in the recent Lynda tutorial I've been watching. Thanks again.